# having issue site made in codeigniter is shifted to new domain

Tags: codeigniter

hey i have a running site which URL is below

> http://www.buraksolutions.com/homelife/site/residential.html

the problem is when i  shifted this site to other domain, there is index.php? coming in the URL which is causing a lot of problem, it does not loads most of data

> http://nextcrawl.net/HomeLife/site/index.php?/welcome_controller.html

here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /kunden/homepages/8/d232327588/htdocs/consulnet/genetech/mockups/nextcrawl/homelife/site
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 

# AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /homelife/site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Have you copied your .htaccess file to your new server?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the URL rewriting that's defined in your .htaccess file.  It's possible that its configuration doesn't match with the new domain name, or mod_rewrite may not even be enabled on your new domain's server.  I can't tell you more than that without looking at your setup, but here are some fantastic resources on URL rewriting with CodeIgniter:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
- http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite